# Gradle Sync Failed with Exception

Tags: android-studio, gradle, kotlin

I’m new developer in kotlin.

I started a new project in android studio, but when the compiler build the project he said Gradle Sync Failed.

so I look on the internet and I am following the instructions (update Gradle) but nothing happens. always the same message “Gradle Sync Failed”.

I tried all day yesterday and this morning to fix it. Anyone can help me.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: go to sdk tools check any updates are required?

Comment: since i updated android studio, i can't open new projects